# Watched and ignored is not displaying for me

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tags

I have two watched tags and 85+ ignored tags.
As of checking the site today (06-09-21 PT), the process of highlighting watched tags and blurring ignored tags does not appear to be functioning the way it was previous to today.

At the top of my question display are the Newest / Active / Bountied / Unanswered / More tabs, and then just to the right of them the Filter widget.  The widget is orange-lit; I don't recall it looking like that before, but it may be something I did not notice until I started looking for explanations.

It is not clear to me whether this is a bug, a change to the site (*eg.*, new filter widget function), or my own personal settings that I have somehow changed without being aware.

Comment: I am experiencing this on Win7 Chrome, but not iOS 14 safari.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I am currently running Chrome

Comment: Main Meta report of the same thing: [Ignored and watched tags seem broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366321/681403)

Comment: Followup to Someone_Evil's comment - the issue's been identified and should be fixed shortly (if it hasn't already been fixed), per the staff's response to the MSE post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Marc Gravell's answer to the linked post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366345/335251):

> Sorry about that. What happened here: the favorites/ignored feature is
> implemented client-side; a UI tweak changed the DOM in a way that
> broke the jQuery selector, meaning that it no longer found the tag
> data. I've put a PR together that fixes this - we'll get it deployed
> as soon as we can (after validation, etc).

And per Marc's subsequent comments there, the bugfix has now been deployed. (Marc has also added the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag to this Q&A accordingly.)